# ExtJS tree throwing error when checkbox is attached to a column

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I'm using an older version of ExtJS ( 3.3.0 to be exact ), I have a TreeGrid ( now I think its called a TreePanel ), inside the tree I'm displaying a list of files, I'm trying to get one of the columns to display a checkbox next to each filename and I keep getting the following error when clicking the checkbox;

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined
```

when I click the filename attached to the error in the js debug console it points me to the following block of code in the ext-all-debug.js file, it seems it doesn't like the line that starts with var;

```
onCheckChange : function(){
    var checked = this.checkbox.checked;

    this.checkbox.defaultChecked = checked;
    this.node.attributes.checked = checked;
    this.fireEvent('checkchange', this.node, checked);
},
```

the column in my code is as follows;

```
{
    header: 'Click Me',
    xtype: 'tgcolumn',
    width: 50,
    tpl: checkTemplate
},
```

and the Ext.XTemplate attached is as follows;

```
var checkTemplate = new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl for=".">',
    '<div class="x-combo-list-item">',
    '<input type="checkbox" name="drugcheckbox[]" value="filedetails" />',
    '</div>',
    '</tpl>'
);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I can't seem to figure it out, I'm pretty new at Ext

Comment: are you getting values in the variable `checked` ?

Comment: @UDID Sorry im not sure what you mean

Comment: In you `onCheckChange` method you are writing this. ` var checked = this.checkbox.checked;` Check in debugger weather are you getting the value of `checked` or not ?

Comment: @UDID the onCheckChange method is brought in by Ext, its not something I have written

Comment: BUt you written this line right ? `var checked = this.checkbox.checked;` I am asking what valu you getting in `checked` ?

Comment: No, I didnt write that ... That block of code including that line comes from ext-all-debug.js

Comment: http://svn.geoext.org/ext/3.3.0/docs/index.html 3.3.0 docs show TreePanel is available. TreeGrid is not there in docs. Is TreeGrid custom component? Also, can you add complete config used with TreeGrid definition?